# Highcharts/Highstock add shapes/flags to multiples panes not just the first pane

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts/Highstock add shapes/flags to multiples panes not just the first pane.

In this js fiddle code:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui

We can add flags or do other operations using the stock tools only on the first pane. Is there a way we are able to do it on the second pane as well.

Answer (score 1):

That functionality is not fully implemented yet. Here you can find a ticket on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12268

As a workaround, you can overwrite `addClipPaths` method to allow annotations to be added independently of the axes.

```
Highcharts.Annotation.prototype.addClipPaths = function() {};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s5e7fy3L/